# Adding Line Break After pattern in VIM

Tags: regex, vim, replace, vi, substitution

I have a css file and I want to add an empty line after every `}`.

How can I do this in Vim?

Comment: Related to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247329/vim-how-to-replace-one-new-line-n-with-two-ns

Answer (score 50, accepted):

A substitution would work nicely.

```
:%s/}/\0\r/g
```

Replace `}` with the whole match `\0` and a new line character `\r`.
or

```
:%s/}/&\r/g
```

Where `&` also is an alternative for the whole match, looks a bit funny though in my opinion. Vim golfers like it because it saves them a keystroke :)

`\0` or `&` in the replacement part of the substitution acts as a special character. During the substitution the whole string that was matched replaces the `\0` or the `&` character in the substitution.

We can demonstrate this with a more complex search and replace -

```
Which witch is which?
```

Apply a substitution -

```
:s/[wW][ih][ti]ch/The \0/g
```

Gives -

```
The Which The witch is The which?
```

Comment: For such a beginner question, an explanation would surely help: `\0` (shorter would be `&`) re-inserts the match, `\r` is the escape sequence for a newline (in a replacement, usually it's `\n`).

Answer (score 8):

```
:%s/pre/cur\r/g
```

`%`: operate on the entire buffer.

`pre`(previous pattern): which pattern will be to changed.

`cur`(current pattern): by which the previous pattern will be changed.

`\r`: new line.

`g`: repeat for every match on a line (default is to just replace the first).

Answer (score 7):

The answer is `:%s/}/}\r/` I guess.